# How to give out the internet from PC(win xp) via wireless-router(dlink dir320)?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-router

I have a dlink dir320 router(dd-wrt firmware) and a PC(winxp) that have the internet connection via usb modem. How to install it to give the internet on a few wi-fi devises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a working network card and that [internet connection sharing](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/crawford_02july01.mspx) is enabled on your windows xp machine.  Then connect your xp machine's network card to the WAN port on your wireless router.  You should set up the network card on the windows machine to use a static internal IP (something in the 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x range) and set up the router to also have a static IP that is different from the xp machine but on the same subnet.

Comment: It's still not working.  What i need to set in router WAN settings?
DHCP server or static IP or someone else?

Comment: @amo Updated with additional instructions.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Can i get an acсess to a files of wifi connected machine from host PC ?

Comment: @amo - yes you can do that, but you need a more advanced configuration.